# When I moved my code into a container, it no longer shows at all in the display window

Tags: python, tkinter

I've moved my code from being the main body into a container as i need to create a different frame. Though when I did this it no longer shows my output.

Put the main body into a frame, expecting it to go about as normal and just become a child to the parent which is the root. What happened instead was the output no longer appearing.

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry('600x300')
root.title('Input Frame')

InputFrame = Frame(root, bg='lightblue')

# label of the app title
title = Label(InputFrame, text='Welcome to the Greeting App!',
              font=("Arial", 20, 'bold'),
              fg='blue',
              bg="lightblue"
              )
title.place(x=50,y=40) 

#label of the name taking and the entry box
userlabel= Label(InputFrame, text='Enter your name...', 
             font=("Arial", 10),
             bg="lightblue"
             )
userlabel.place(x=150,y=95)

userentry = Entry(InputFrame,
             font=("Arial", 12)
             )
userentry.place(x=150,y=120)

#now this is the menu of the dropping down, selection of color!
selcolor = Label(InputFrame, text="Select a color...",
                font=("Arial", 10),
                bg="lightblue"
                )
selcolor.place(x=150,y=160)

colors = [
    "blue",
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "green",
    "black"
]

#sel means selected, but shortened
sel = StringVar()
sel.set("black")

menu = OptionMenu(InputFrame, sel, *colors)
menu.place(x=150,y=185)

#button for updating greetin'
btn = Button(InputFrame, text='Update Greeting'
             )
btn.place(x=240,y=235)

InputFrame.place()




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that you're using `place` rather than `pack` or `grid`. Unlike the other two, `place` will not cause a containing widget to expand to fit the size of the children. It is up to you to set the size of all widgets.

Because you are using `place`, and because you didn't set an explicit size, the size of `InputFrame` is 1x1. It is there, but only one pixel in size so it's hard to see. You can verify this by giving the window an explicit size so that it becomes visibile:

```
InputFrame.place(width=200, height=200)
```

That's not a proper fix, that's just a debugging tool to show you that the frame is actually there with all of its children.

I would say that the best solution is to use `pack` to have that frame fill the window:

```
InputFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```